# In makefile, how do I process multiple targets in one call?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using a private script that routinely converts multiple (~100) text files to HTML. I wrote a makefile to only convert text files with changes:

```
TEXT_DIR = /path/to/app/data/
OUTPUT_DIR = /path/to/app/reports/

.PHONY : html

html : $(wildcard $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*.html)

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.html : $(TEXT_DIR)/%.txt
    generate_html --html $< $@
```

When I run `make`, it calls the script once per each changed file:

```
generate_html --html /path/to/app/data/file1.txt /path/to/app/reports/file1.html
generate_html --html /path/to/app/data/file2.txt /path/to/app/reports/file2.html
generate_html --html /path/to/app/data/file3.txt /path/to/app/reports/file3.html
```

This is quite slow, because the script takes a bit of time on initial load as it reads config and does setup. Processing all files in a single run is much faster:

```
generate_html --html /path/to/app/data/file1.txt /path/to/app/reports/file1.html --html /path/to/app/data/file2.txt /path/to/app/reports/file2.html --html /path/to/app/data/file3.txt /path/to/app/reports/file3.html
```

How do I make GNU Make run the script like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables to store the files that has to be changed, instead of actually running the command directly in `${OUTPUT_DIR}/%.html` target.

```
TEXT_DIR = /path/to/app/data/
OUTPUT_DIR = /path/to/app/reports/

.PHONY : html

html : $(wildcard $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*.html)
    generate_html ${TODO}

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.html : $(TEXT_DIR)/%.txt
    $(eval TODO=${TODO} --html $< $@)
```

Comment: It works! However, when there are no changed files to convert, Make still executes `generate_html`, causing an error (`${TODO}` expands to nothing). Is it possible to prevent `generate_html` from running when there are no more targets?

Comment: You can add a - before the command.. i.e. `-generate_html ...`. This will make the command to ignore errors from that command, if thats what you want. Otherwise I think there might be someway by using conditionals to avoid executing.

Comment: Did you try the other answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858195/7075416 ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind creating a file that holds the last build time (i.e. `last-run.txt` here), you can do this. Here I'm using `$?` to get all the text files that are newer than `last-run.txt`. cf. [GNU Make Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

```
TEXT_DIR = /path/to/app/data
OUTPUT_DIR = /path/to/app/reports

build_html_name = $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(notdir $(1:.txt=.html))

.PHONY: html
html: last-run.txt

last-run.txt: $(wildcard $(TEXT_DIR)/*.txt)
    ./generate_html $(foreach f,$?,--html $f $(call build_html_name,$f))
    date > $@
```

The contents of `last-run.txt` doesn't matter as long as the file's modified time gets updated; so `touch $@` instead of `date > $@` does the job.

Comment: It works, though I don't like having a dummy file named `html` in the current directory. +1 for not calling `generate_html` when there is nothing to do.

Comment: Hi @PhilKang , I thought it's good to present the simpler code that shows the idea while keeping the way you run the target as is, i.e. `make html`. Anyway, I've extended my answer a bit and split into two rules so that you can still keep `make html` while giving better name for the timestamp file.